# Как обратиться к элементу до текста и после текста?

Tags: html, css

Как сдвинуть крестик на одинаковое растояние от текста, но без изменения `html` кода?

Хотелось бы такое сделать только при помощи `css`

```css
div i:first-child {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
div i:last-child {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><i>+</i> Текст</div>
<div>Текст <i>+</i></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот вариант, только при условии, что div потомок одного родителя

```css
div:nth-child(1) i {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
div:nth-child(2) i {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><i>+</i> Текст</div>
<div>Текст <i>+</i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант сработает, только если обернуть "Текст" в какой-нибудь тег, например `<span>`.

```css
div i:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
div i:last-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><i>+</i><span>Текст</span></div>
<div><span>Текст</span><i>+</i></div>
```

Тогда `:first-child` и `:last-child` будут считаться корректно, а так текст не является элементом и в первом случае из вашего примера, `<i>` является и первым, и последним элементом, но т.к. в записи `:last-child` указан последним, то будет перезаписывать `:first-child` из-за чего видно, что отступ идёт слева.